# Search and Order results by keywords

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I'm trying to create a search on a collection of `Organisation`s (I'm using LINQ to Entities).

```cs
public class Organisation
{
    public string OrgName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string OverviewOfServices { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
}
```

The user inputs some keywords, and then I want to return all `Organisation`s where **all** the keywords exist in any of the `Organisation` fields above.

```cs
// 1.  Remove special characters and create an array of keywords
string[] Keywords = CleanKeyWordString(model.keyword)

// 2 . Get organisations
orglist = _UoW.OrganisationRepo.All();
```

(`OrganisationRepo.All` returns an `IQueryable` of `Organisation`. There are further queries on the search prior to this)

```cs
// 3. Filter results by keywords
orglist = (from org in orglist
           where Keywords.All(s => 
               org.OrgName.ToLower().Contains(s) 
            || org.OverviewOfServices.ToLower().Contains(s) 
            || org.ContactName.Contains(s) 
            || org.Address1.ToLower().Contains(s) 
            || org.Town.ToLower().Contains(s) 
            || org.PostCode.ToLower().Contains(s) 
            || org.Keywords.ToLower().Contains(s))
           orderby searchTerms.Any(s => org.OrgName.ToLower().Contains(s)) ? 1 : 2 
           select org);
```

This brings back the required results, however, I would now like to order them so that those records with the keywords in the title are ordered first and then the rest after.

Is this possible without adding some kind of ranking algorithm to the results?

Comment: Off topic: I would recommend picking either query syntax or the Lambda expression syntax for your LINQ queries. Mixing them like this is confusing and inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var withRank = orglist
    .Select(o => 
        new { 
            Org = o, 
            Rank = o.OrgName.ToLower().Contains(s) 
        });
var orderedOrgList = withRank
    .OrderBy(o => o.Rank)
    .Select(o => o.Org);
```